# an event-handing question in javascript

Tags: javascript, event-handling

If I define a function like this:

```
function doSomething()
{
    this.style.color = '#cc0000';
}
```

Do

```
element.attachEvent('onclick',doSomething)
```

and

```
element.addEventListener('click',doSomething,false)
```

get the same result? And why?Thanks a lot.

Comment: No. When using attachEvent in IE, the listener's this keyword is set differently to how it is set by addEventListener in every other browser. In IE, this within the function will be window, in other browsers it will be the element that the listener is attached to.

Comment: Am I correct that this code is from [this page](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html) on PPK's QuirksMode site? What, *specifically*, are you having trouble with in his explanation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, but in different browsers.

- `attachEvent` is the method you have to use in IE.
- `addEventListener` is available in all other browsers (Firefox, Chrome, Safari, Opera, etc).
  It is the W3C standard. IE9 tries to be more compatible with W3C and supports it too.

I suggest to read [*Advanced event registration models*](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_advanced.html) which explains the browser differences quite well.

You should also read the [other articles about events on quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/contents.html#events). They will give you a good in event handling in general.

Comment: IE9 supports addEventListener nowadays

Comment: `this` will be the global object inside `doSomething()` using `attachEvent()` whereas it will be the element using `addEventListener`, so the OP's code won't work in the first case.

Comment: @TimDown: Oh really? I didn't know that (clearly I don't have so much *practical* IE experience ;)).

Comment: Yep, definitely. I'd suggest adding a note to your answer for future readers, because it's misleading at the moment: the OP's code won't work in IE because of the `this` problem.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much, addEventListener is the W3C way of adding events and supported by most browsers, while attachEvent is an IE thing and supported mainly by them. [Read more](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_advanced.html).